# Auto Import Visual Studio Code not working in jsx

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, jsx, auto-import

Any idea how to enable auto import suggestion inside `jsx` ?

[image: Inside jsx]

This is weird because if I'm typing outside of the `jsx`, it gives me the auto import suggestion.

[image: Outside jsx]

I'm not installing any snippets or `Auto Import` Extension, or `Visual Studio IntelliCode`.

But even though I installed them, it doesn't help this issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I added the below code in `settings.json` and It worked.

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.jsx": "javascriptreact",
    "*.js": "javascriptreact"
}
```

If you want to have react in JS files, you can add the below code

```
// FOR THE HTML EMMET IN REACT BELOW
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue: [Auto-imports from within jsx don't work](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44657)
 will apparently be fixed in vscode v1.58.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_58.md#typescript-435

> TypeScript 4.3.5
>
> We now bundle TS 4.3.5. This minor update fixes a few important bugs,
> including auto imports not working in JSX.

Comment: Thank's for your help