# Visual studio Code autoimport doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-code, auto-import

I am using VSCode autoimport on daily basis with this extension
soates autoimport.
https://github.com/soates/Auto-Import/issues/104.
It suddenly stopped to work. I have tried reinstall vscode, changing extension version, disabling plugins, clearing cache ...etc
I have tried this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1yu5tB4KOis and also tried add
`checkjs: true` to my `jsconfig.json`. Its very hard to live without auto import.

these are my settings.json

```json
{
  "dart.flutterSdkPath": "C:\\Users\\rolni\\AppData\\Roaming\\flutter_windows_v1.12.13+hotfix.9-stable\\flutter\\bin",
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Material Theme Darker]": {
      "statusBar.debuggingBackground": "#212121"
    }
  },
  "material-icon-theme.folders.associations": {
    "global_state": "global",
    "ui": "layout",
    "bloc": "controller"
  },
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "debug.node.autoAttach": "on",
  "[json]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
      "strings": true
    },
    "editor.suggest.insertMode": "replace",
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "notebook.kernelProviderAssociations": [],
  "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
  "emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true,
  "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
  "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "highlight-matching-tag.customEmptyElements": null,
  "emmet.excludeLanguages": [
    "markdown"
  ],
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "html"
  },
  "autoimport.filesToScan": "**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}",
  "autoimport.showNotifications": true,
  "extensions.ignoreRecommendations": true,
  "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
  "outline.showVariables": false,
  "debug.javascript.autoAttachFilter": "disabled",
  "debug.javascript.terminalOptions": {
    "trace": true
  },
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[jsonc]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features"
  },
  "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7-preview\\pwsh.exe",
  "debug.onTaskErrors": "debugAnyway",
  "[go]": {
    "editor.insertSpaces": false
  },
  "go.formatTool": "gofmt",
  "go.useLanguageServer": true,
  "gopls": {
    "usePlaceholders": true, // add parameter placeholders when completing a function
  },
  "todo-tree.tree.showScanModeButton": false,
  "todo-tree.highlights.customHighlight": {
    "TODO": {
      "icon": "check",
      "type": "line",
      "iconColour": "yellow",
      "foreground": "red",
      "background": "yellow"
    },
    "FIXME": {
      "icon": "beaker",
      "iconColour": "red",
      "foreground": "white",
      "background": "red"
    }
  },
  "debug.inlineValues": true,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.organizeImports": true
  },
  "[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
  "gitlens.hovers.currentLine.over": "line",
  "terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": true,
  "go.toolsManagement.autoUpdate": true,
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Material Theme",
  "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
  "todo-tree.general.tags": [
    "BUG",
    "HACK",
    "FIXME",
    "TODO",
    "XXX",
    "[ ]",
    "[x]"
  ],
  "todo-tree.regex.regex": "(//|#|<!--|;|/\\*|^|^\\s*(-|\\d+.))\\s*($TAGS)",
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
}
```

Can't also debug extension all my breakpoints are unbound...can't figure out how to debug it to find root cause of problem.

This log is in my output Log (Extension Host)

```
[error] [vscode.json-language-features] provider FAILED
[2021-07-05 13:23:44.550] [exthost] [error] Canceled: Canceled
    at b.makeCancelError (c:\Users\rolni\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\json-language-features\client\dist\node\jsonClientMain.js:1:64563)
    at b.handleFailedRequest (c:\Users\rolni\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\json-language-features\client\dist\node\jsonClientMain.js:1:64414)
    at c:\Users\rolni\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\json-language-features\client\dist\node\jsonClientMain.js:1:24756
```

EDIT:
I have tried remove plugins, directories, settings, but still
autoimport extension is not enabled even it says yes. Its even missing
the log in extension host output.

Comment: It's "possible" this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68264915/836330.  But it might just be an extension issue and not anything vscode can fix.

Answer (score 1):

**For JavaScript projects**

VSCode in general starts to fail after a while, it OFTEN doesn't suggest imports from package dependencies and even starts to stop hinting auto import for local project src folder files...

As soon as you open the file it will all of a sudden become available...

It's not a plugin issue, it's just VS code, it's starting to get bloated...

**For TypeScript projects**

It's not so bad, they seem mainly focused on TS these days, but when it goes wrong it goes wrong. I've started un-installing, go to install folders make sure nothing is there and re-install and it works again. No login sync.

**Alternative (which I am not a fan off but just works... grrr)**

PHPStorm / WebStorm, it gets the import right every time.

And ctrl click on sub methods of class's will auto open that file and locate you on that method. VSCode will just open that file, if it can find it...

With auto complete (in JS Projects) on variables assigned to a class. I think VS Code will only do that if the file is open in the editor.

I keep both open now, VSCode for speed of editing but when (not if) VSCode start to play up, I switch over. Also for the stacking of file tabs feature in PHPStorm instead of a scroll bar of tabs. I find it easier to just switch over to PHPStorm and back again instead of that scroll thing.